# Is there a container ordered by primary and secondary keys?

Tags: c++, qt

I am looking for something like `QMultiMap` from the Qt library, but with two keys.

I would like to be able to do these things:

```
template<TPrimaryKey, TSecondaryKey, TItem>
class Container;
...
Container<int, int, std::string> container;
container.insert(2, 2, "pear");
container.insert(1, 1, "apple");
container.insert(1, 2, "orange");
for (auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
```

and the output will be:

```
apple
orange
pear
```

That is items sorted according to `TPrimaryKey` and when there are more items with the same `TPrimaryKey` they will be sorted by `TSecondaryKey`.

Is there some freely available container with similar functionality?

Comment: This kind of ordering is called "lexicographic" (e.g., alphabetic order is one example of a lexicographic order). The standard `std::pair` class template uses that in its comparison operators, so you can just use a pair to store the keys. With C++11, the `std::tuple` does the same for more keys. Then, use any ordered container you like (e.g., `std::set`, `std::map`, `std::multimap`, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For STL, you could make a map where the key is a pair:

```
std::map< std::pair<int, int>, std::string > container;
```

You might still be able to use the pair for the Qt container, though you won't have quite the same interface as what you suggested.

Comment: Thank you! That is simple and smart.